# Are tattoos allowed in Islam?

Tags: sharia

Are tattoos allowed or not in Islam? If they are not allowed, please explain the details.

Answer (score 0):

Tattoo is **Haraam**

Because we have no right to change the creation of allah.

HADITH:

Narrated 'Abdullah: Allah has cursed those women who practise tattooing and those who get themselves tattooed, and those who remove their face hairs, and those who create a space between their teeth artificially to look beautiful, and such women as change the features created by Allah. Why then should I not curse those whom the Prophet has cursed? And that is in Allah's Book. i.e. His Saying: 'And what the Apostle gives you take it and what he forbids you abstain (from it).' (Quran 59.7)

Reference: (Sahih Bukhari 815)